# why my output "Nama" didn't get Ascending Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sorting

Given the following query:

```
SELECT NIM, Nama
FROM mahasiswa
ORDER BY NIM, Nama;
```

I'm getting the following output:

| NIM | Nama |
| --- | --- |
| 10296055 | Lia A |
| 10296126 | Siti |
| 10296130 | Deden A |
| 10296135 | Ayu |
| 10296140 | Didit K |
| 10296145 | Yogi Adi |
| 10296187 | Andriana |
| 10296188 | Rafi |

Only the "NIM" gets sorted by Ascending. Why the column "Nama" didn't get sorted?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is sorted that how it works, if you have duplicate on the first column then it will sort the second column. Check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aeb46c6792fa1278d20ce5e3ede63b52

Comment: When one column is sorted then another one will be unsorted, and backward. It is not possible to receive the output where two columns values are sorted at the same time. Until the greater value in one column matches the greater value in another column for any rows pair strictly.

Comment: *`ORDER BY NIM, Nama`* means the next: sort rows by `NIM`, if some rows have the same value in this columns then sort these rows (only these, not all) by `Nama` additionally.

Comment: 'why the column "Nama" didn't get sorted' - it did , the instruction is to order name within nim and since nim is unique there is no apparent sort on nama. Please add your expected outcome to help clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order on both the two columns, you need to add an order number to each of the two columns and match these two. You can get the order for each column using the window function `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT t1.NIM, 
       t2.Nama 
FROM       (SELECT NIM,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NIM) AS ord
            FROM tab                                       ) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Nama,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Nama) AS ord
            FROM tab                                       ) t2
ON t1.ord = t2.ord
```

Check this [SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Q9zvARR7ya9T55rYhYpLE/1).

Comment: A little problem, the query will produce wrong results. Example  `10296187 | Andriana`, in your query `10296187 Siti`

Comment: It's exactly what it does: it does not consider the association between the two columns. At least this is my interpretation of this problem, I may be wrong. If he wanted to sort only on second column, but keeping the association between columns, he could've inverted the order of the columns inside the `GROUP BY` clause. Akina's comment is insightful regarding the ordering.